# How to force a Manipulator inside a Manipulate to auto-run?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, animation

I want to use a slider (not drop-down list) for a list of `discreteValues` to do the `Manipulate` (I used `Sin[x]` below for simplicity, but the actual one is much more complicated). At the same time, I needed to show a function of x next to the slider (below I used `x^2` as an example).

Besides, since the output would be used by other notebook, I would use `SaveDefinitions -> True`.

```
discreteValues = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.6, 2.0, 2.2};

Manipulate[Sin[x],Row[{Control[{x, discreteValues, Manipulator, AutoAction -> False}], Dynamic[x^2]}], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

By default, the slider won't auto-run. How can I force the slider to auto-run by default?

I tried to simply change `Manipulate` to `Animate`, but I got the error.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `Manipulator` with `Animator`:

```
Manipulate[Sin[x], 
 Row[{Control[{x, discreteValues, Animator}], Dynamic[x^2]}], 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```